# About printf and scanf

Tags: c

What is the meaning that `printf` and `scanf`  commands are the part of C language, as they don't need inclusion of `#include<stdio.h>`.

Why aren't others part of the C language?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You _do_ need to include `stdio.h` to use `printf` and `scanf` (or at least provide proper prototypes, but that would not be the preferred way). And yes, they are part of the C language standard.

Comment: The question before the edit was about `(print f)` and `(scan f)` ... perhaps this is actually a [lisp] question.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the mean that,(print f) and (scan f) commands are the part of c language

They are not "commands", but rather **functions,** and they aren't part of the language either.

> they don't need inclusion of #include

They do. **They need the headers/declarations even more than others,** since they are variadic. Not providing a prototype for them will quickly lead to undefined behavior.

> why don't others be the part of c language

Again, these aren't part of the language because... because they are not part of the language. They are **stand-alone functions,** which don't contribute to the core syntax and semantics of a C program. They aren't included in C's context-free grammar. **The C standard does describe them, though - since they *are* part of the C standard library.**

Answer (score 4):

Actually, no, they are not part of the language in the way you think they are. If you call `print("hello, %d", 5);` it will create an implicit declaration based on the parameters you've provided and the returning type will be `int`.

Luckily, there is a match for this in `libc` which is implicitly linked to your program, and linker will be able to link your source file and the library definition of `printf`.

Comment: Your last sentence most likely clears his doubt.

Answer (score 0):

**[`printf()` and `scanf()` Example programs](http://fresh2refresh.com/c/c-printf-and-scanf/)**

In layman language

`printf()` is a function use to display (output)

`scanf()` is a function used for reading any input

Comment: `scanf` does not allocates space, the arguments must be pointers to allocated space

Answer (score 0):

In certain IDE, it is possible that `printf` & `scanf` are used and not underlined as false while editig the source code, because of the indexer which knows these functions exists. But you will not be able to compile it. The include is not optional as the compiler itselfs doesn't know printf nor scanf.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` and `scanf` aren't part of the *grammar*, but they are part of the *language* by virtue of being in the standard library as specified by the language definition.  You *do* need to include `stdio.h` to use them properly, though.